# close session inside a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rails-engines

I have an engine called coupons inside my rails application, I want to close session but it gives me an error that says the URL does not exist, but outside the engine it is possible to close session:

```
<a href="<%= main_app.destroy_user_session_path %>"
    method: "delete"
    class="btn-login-type">log out
</a>
```

**The error I get:**

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

(as I said, this works outside the engine, but not inside)